# Add reference of a method in SOAP Webservice in a class

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have a method called `GetTime()` in my SOAP WebService called `Service.asmx` and I am trying to call that method in my `form.cs` to get the time from the server. Can anybody tell me how to add reference to the `GetTime()` in `Service.asmx`?

Comment: Service s = new Service(); s.GetTime(); ?

Comment: I don't think I am looking for this. There is a autogenerated code in Reference.cs which has reference to all the methods in Service.asmx and which are used by methods in Form.cs. Basically this reference.cs connects my Form.cs and Service.asmx.

Comment: In form.cs add a using line for the namespace that is at the top of your Reference.cs, so it can see the classes that are in it.
Look in Reference.cs for a class with name ending "Client". Then do as j.v. said, but instead of 'Service' use the name of that client class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was because my references were not updated. So right clicked on my Web Reference and Updated my Web References and then it was able to recognize the method I defined in the Service.